# How can I install Perl's Event::Lib on Mac OS X?

Tags: perl, macos, module

I want to install Realplexor (a Perl comet server) on Mac and it requires

```
 # apt-get install libevent-dev gcc
 # perl -MCPAN -e "install Event::Lib"
```

I installed the first one using:

```
 port install libevent
```

but I can't find "Event::Lib" with port nor fink.

Does anyone know how I could install that dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At your superuser commandline type:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

At the CPAN prompt type:

```
install Event::Lib
```

You can find more information on CPAN modules at [CPAN's Website](http://www.cpan.org)

Comment: thanks it seems to work, could i do the same for libevent-dev instead of using port?

Comment: Nope cannot use CPAN to install libevent-dev. Port install is the way to go on your Mac installation, CPAN is only for CPAN modules.

Comment: Or, to make that shorter, `% cpan Event::Lib`